# Dump database during RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing a gem for catching flaky tests. The idea is to dump database to locate randomized factory. I'm using system call in the .after hook:

```
config.after do |example|
   system "pg_dump -U postgres -d #{db_name} > #{path}/#{status}.sql"
end
```

At this moment database contains a record - i've made sure of that by byebug.
However i bump into a problem - as i see, transaction is not closed, so if i try get record via psql - i get nothing, record doesn't exist.
Any ideas how to close transaction during spec? Or maybe i'm wrong somewhere deeply?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the matter is the transaction was not closed. Database cleaner wrap all rspec execution in begin-rollback. I found two ways to solve my problem:

1. Use active record connection to dump database content, but it's no so easy - you have to use COPY command to copy (unexpected, huh?) ALL tables to file (.csv for example) and then restore them. Ew, tedious.
2. Change database cleaner strategie from :transaction to :truncation:

```
  config.before(:each, flaky: true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end
```

That's the solution.

Comment: Note that the requirement for Databasecleaner at all will make your gem less popular, and the requirement for the truncation strategy as well. Iterating with ActiveRecord through all the existing tables might be the more sustainable approach :/

Comment: Have a look in the rails_admin gem for example how it figures out all the existing models https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/a2fd16b9f3684b434a3b28bbae5303cceb536e49/lib/rails_admin/config.rb#L336

Comment: that's a reasonable suggestion, i'll consider it, thank you